# Access data passed from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new in learning asp.net MVC and am trying to access some data from the controller in my view. This is my code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string subcategory)
{
    List<Object> products = db.ListOfProducts(subcategory);

    return View(products);
}
```

I know that after passing the LIST into the VIEW there should be some way to acces the data in the VIEW but I can't seem to figure out how.
Normally when I create a view based on a model I know that by using the model object I can acces the data I need, but usually theres a definiton on the top regarding the model and in my caase there is none.

So how can I acces the LISTS data in my view?

Comment: You can look at this where the data is bound to a web grid : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351853/mvc-3-populate-bind-webgrid-form-ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the top of your view to define the model type:

```
@model List<Object>
```

You may need to namespace this as either:

```
@using Systems.Collections.Generic;
@model List<Object>
```

or

```
@model Systems.Collections.Generic.List<Object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just create a strong type view by adding to your view

```
 @model IList<Products>
```

after that you can iterate throw you model like this:

```
@foreach(var prod in Model)
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a corrosponding view in your Views folder called Index (in a sub-folder that matches your controller name - so if you controller is called `HomeController` you will need a 'Home' folder underneath the views folder) If you don't already have a view you can create one by right-clicking on the folder and clicking 'Add view'.

Ensure you have a statement at the top of the view which reads:

```
@model Systems.Collections.Generic.List<object>
```

You should now be able to access your data via the `Model` property of your view.