# Populate webgrid on search

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am trying to populate my webgrid on search.

I used this solution: [Bind WebGrid form AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351853/mvc-3-populate-bind-webgrid-form-ajax).

But the problem with it is when i click on the webgrid "order by", it fails.

EDIT:

you can see in the example it puts the grid in an external file named _Buildings.cshtml, and it loads it as PartialView. So when I put on the grid to "order by", it calls the method i used to populate the grid with GET, now you can see in the example it doest have a 'GetFacilityDetails' with get so it gets 404. and if i change the 'GetFacilityDetails' to get it will only return the partial and not the whole page

Comment: What does it mean, it fails? Do you receive an exception? What exception? How your code essentially looks?

Comment: editted.. please see